# Can we programmatically access Process Control Block in MS Windows?

Tags: c++

Can we programmatically access Process Control Block in MS Windows?
If yes, then how (c/c++/jave etc)

Comment: what are you trying to do?  Which part of the PCB are you after?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, via `NtQueryInformationProcess`. Note however that its contents are mostly undocumented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Look at some software like procxp to understand how to access these blocks in MS windows. Of course you should access and call some of windows system calls and base API to gain access to elevated mode (I mean super user mode or kernel mode) modify such these things.